# how to stop apache2 via kill -9

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, mysql, sudo

I know the normal method to start or stop apache2 on linux is:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start|stop
```

Or…

```
sudo service apache2 start|stop
```

Or…

```
sudo systemctl start|stop apache2
```

But, in an emergency, I want to stop the processes with the "kill" command. For this I use the following command to stop the PID:

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep -i '[a]pache*' | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null; done
```

out

```
user@user:~$ ps -ef | grep -i '[a]pache*'
root      173437       1  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  173438  173437  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  173439  173437  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
user@user:~$ for pid in $(ps -ef | grep -i '[a]pache*' | awk '{print $2}'); do sudo kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null; done
user@user:~$ ps -ef | grep -i '[a]pache*'
root      174321       1  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  174322  174321  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  174323  174321  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

... and new apache2 PIDs come out

what's wrong with this command?

thanks

PD: I found this command on this site a long time ago, but I don't remember where and therefore I can't reference to the author. I apologize for that

Comment: How does your Apache start? If it works as a systemd service then maybe there is `Restart=` specified and systemd restarts the service. In other words: the service works as designed.

Comment: `apache2.service` is configure `Restart=on-abort`. I guess that's why my command doesn't work. So there is no use killing the PID. I have to kill the process. Thank you. If you wish, you can give a more complete answer to select it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned `systemctl stop apache2`, maybe because your Apache starts as a systemd service. If so, then the reason it gets restarted is most likely `Restart=` in the relevant service unit configuration file (`apache2.service`).

See [`man 5 systemd.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=):

> `Restart=`
> Configures whether the service shall be restarted when the service process exits, is killed, or a timeout is reached. […]
>
> Takes one of `no`, `on-success`, `on-failure`, `on-abnormal`, `on-watchdog`, `on-abort`, or `always`. If set to `no` (the default), the service will not be restarted. […]

Read the manual to learn the meaning of each possible value. *Maybe* you want `Restart=no`. If not, don't miss this fragment:

> As exceptions to the setting above, the service will not be restarted if the exit code or signal is specified in `RestartPreventExitStatus=` […] or the service is stopped with `systemctl stop` or an equivalent operation. Also, the services will always be restarted if the exit code or signal is specified in `RestartForceExitStatus=` […].

If you want to use e.g. `Restart=on-abort` and still to be able to kill Apache with SIGKILL (`kill -s KILL` or `kill -9`) and not have it resurrected, consider placing

```
RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGKILL
```

in the unit configuration file.

Note SIGKILL should be used as a last resort. `systemctl stop` should be your earlier choice. I don't know what "emergency" you meant, but the fact the service got restarted makes me believe systemd was operational and most likely `systemctl stop apache2` would work.